# Delphi TPerlRegEx ReplaceAll between 2 word

Tags: regex, delphi

i have text like (with new line etc.), eg.:

```
[my_tag]foo[/my_tag]
  bar baz [my_tag]bar 
foo[/my_tag] 
foo [my_tag]bar baz
foo[/my_tag]
```

i want totally remove all `[my_tag][/my_tag]` content, eg.:

```
[my_tag][/my_tag]
  bar baz [my_tag][/my_tag] 
foo [my_tag][/my_tag]
```

my code not work (it seems not match newline):

```
var
  aPerlRegEx : TPerlRegEx;
  aContent   : string;
begin
  aContent := '';
  aContent := aContent + '[my_tag]foo[/my_tag]' + #13#10;
  aContent := aContent + 'bar baz [my_tag]bar ' + #13#10;
  aContent := aContent + 'foo[/my_tag] '        + #13#10;
  aContent := aContent + 'foo [my_tag]bar baz'  + #13#10;
  aContent := aContent + 'foo[/my_tag] '        + #13#10;

  aPerlRegEx := TPerlRegEx.Create;
  try
    with aPerlRegEx do begin
       Options     := [preCaseLess, preMultiLine];
       RegEx       := '\[my_tag\].*?\[\/my_tag\]';
       Subject     := aContent;
       Replacement := '';
    end;

    if aPerlRegEx.Match then
        aPerlRegEx.ReplaceAll;

    writeln(aPerlRegEx.Subject);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(aPerlRegEx);
  end;
```

Comment: Can these tags be nested?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no..

Comment: Then you must add the `preSingleLine` flag. And remove `preMultiLine`

Comment: yes @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say these tags cannot be nested, you can **use your regex**

```
\[my_tag\].*?\[\/my_tag\]
```

**With the `preSingleLine` flag to make the `.` match newline symbols**. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lI5mU6/1) (`s` option is used at the demo site).

Note that you can safely remove `preMultiLine` since you do not have `^` and `$` in yout pattern to redefine the behavior of.

**Or**, you can unroll the lazy dot matching pattern for better performance:

```
\[my_tag\][^[]*(?:\[(?!\/my_tag\])[^[]*)*\[\/my_tag\]
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lI5mU6/2). You do not have to use `preSingleLine` flag then as the negated character class `[^[]` match newlines, too.